# select columns in select query from another mapping table

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for select query with dynamic column names that can be derived from another table. Below the sample data and query I am looking to get.

```
create table mapping_tmp (
string_number  varchar,
mapping_name varchar
)

create table fact_tmp (
product varchar,
product_family varchar,
string1 varchar,
string2  varchar,
string3 varchar,
string4 varchar,
string5 varchar
)

insert into mapping_tmp values ('string1','commodity');
insert into mapping_tmp values ('string2','real commodity');
insert into mapping_tmp values ('string3','country');
insert into mapping_tmp values ('string4','region');
insert into mapping_tmp values ('string5','area');

insert into fact_tmp values ('P1','PF1','ABC1','DEF1','GHI1','JKL1','MNO1');
insert into fact_tmp values ('P2','PF2','ABC2','DEF2','GHI2','JKL2','MNO2');
insert into fact_tmp values ('P3','PF3','ABC3','DEF3','GHI3','JKL3','MNO3');
insert into fact_tmp values ('P4','PF4','ABC4','DEF4','GHI4','JKL4','MNO4');
insert into fact_tmp values ('P5','PF5','ABC5','DEF5','GHI5','JKL5','MNO5');
insert into fact_tmp values ('P6','PF6','ABC6','DEF6','GHI6','JKL6','MNO6');
```

Expected output, select fields should be taken from mapping_tmp and those fields data should be displayed in select result.

```
select product,
(select string_number from mapping_tmp where mapping_name = 'country') as country,
(select string_number from mapping_tmp where mapping_name = 'area') as area
from fact_tmp;
```

The actual query is
    select product, string3 as country, string5 as area from fact_tmp;

and the output:

```
product country area
1   P1  GHI1    MNO1
2   P2  GHI2    MNO2
3   P3  GHI3    MNO3
4   P4  GHI4    MNO4
5   P5  GHI5    MNO5
6   P6  GHI6    MNO6
```

I am looking for simple sql query, I cannot use stored procedure or function in application.

Comment: Could you show us your expect result format?

Comment: # product country area
1 P1 GHI1 MNO1
2 P2 GHI2 MNO2
3 P3 GHI3 MNO3
4 P4 GHI4 MNO4
5 P5 GHI5 MNO5
6 P6 GHI6 MNO6

It will look something like this.

Comment: The actual query is "select product,
string3 as country,
string5 as area
from fact_tmp;" I am trying to get string3 dynamically.

Comment: Do not add additional details in comments, it's unreadable. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53772973/edit) your question and add all relevant details.

Comment: I have edited. Any answers/suggestions ?

Comment: If I get this right you want to chose which column gets selected via the mapping table? Ain't gonna happen in plain SQL... You'd need dynamic SQL for that or (re)build the query in the application.

Comment: can you please given example of dynamic SQL?